# google analytics altering link in worpress with elementor and cookiebot

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, elementor, cookiebot

We have a issue regarding wordpress with elementor, google analytics and cookiebot installed.

Our issue is that google analytics alters urls when rejecting cookies, resulting in elementor popups not working.

Elementor owns popup rely on the url hashtag to trigger the popup (example link on button: https://url/test#popupshow), but the google analytics adds a query string to link resulting in the browser navigating (example of changed link: https://url/test?_ga=fwfiuhwe#popupshow), breaking the popup functionality.

Has anybody else encountered this issue and have a solution.

any help would be appreciated

kind regards
Henrik

Tried to search for a solution with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the issue was in google analytics. Had to alter an option in google consent mode, deactivating altering urls.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).